# Como concatenar colunas de tabelas diferentes?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá estou com esse código e estou tentando fazer uma adaptação para usa-lo, mas estou com problema de trazer o conteúdo da coluna editar da tabela quant_img, mas não estou sabendo como.
Os amigos poderiam me dar uma luz de como posso fazer!!!!

Abaixo relaciono o código:

```
    <?php
    include 'cabecalho.php';
    ?>
    <?php
        include '../conexao.php';

                $editar = $_POST['editar']; 
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quant_img");
                $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    ?>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

    <div align="center"  style="margin: 0 0 0 180px; max-width:1000px; width: 90%;">
    <div align="left" style="margin:0 0 0 10px;"><h3>Atualização de Produtos</h3></div>

    <div align="center" style=" padding:2px; width:655px; height:auto; float:left;">

        <div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:315px; height:auto; float:left;">
    <label>Entre com o código do produto</label>
    <form action="prod_consulta.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="busca" method="post">
    <input size="6" type="text" value="" name="buscar"/>
        <input type="submit" name="busca" value="Buscar Produto"/>
    </form>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:1000px; height:auto; border-top:solid 2px; float:left;">

    <br />

    <?php

    $buscar = $_POST['buscar']; 
    $sql_listar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE codigo LIKE '%$buscar%'");

    $total_registros = mysql_num_rows($sql_listar);

        if(mysql_num_rows($sql_listar) <= 0){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Desculpe! Nenhum produto foi encontrado com esse código!");
                window.location.href = "prod_upd.php";
                </script>';
        }else{

        while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql_listar)){
            $codigo = $res['codigo'];

            $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
            $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
            $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
            $preco = $_POST['preco'];
            $codcategoria = $_POST['codcategoria'];
            $codmarca = $_POST['codmarca'];
            $img01 = $_POST['img01'];

            $conteudotabela .= '<tr style="color:#090;">

                    <td align="center">'.$res['codigo'].'</td>

                    <td align="center">'.$res['titulo'].'</td>

                    <td align="center">'.$res['preco'].'</td>

                    <td align="center">
                    <img width="100" height="auto" src="../img_produtos/'.$res['img01'].'" /></td>

                    <td align="center">

                    <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="'.$res['editar'].'?codigo='.$res['codigo'].'">
                    <img width="25" src="../img/edit.png" title="Editar Produto código '.$res['codigo'].'"/>
                    </a>

                    <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="prod_del.php?codigo='.$res['codigo'].'">
                    <img width="25" src="../img/del.png" title="Excluir Produto código '.$res['codigo'].'"/>
                    </a>
                    </td>

                </tr>';
        }


    ?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

    <table class="tbllista" style="width: 15%">
        <thead>
            <tr align="center">
                <th style="width: 5%"></th>
                <th style="width: 5%">
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <table class="tbllista" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr align="center">
                <th align="center">Código</th>
                <th align="center">Título</th>
                <th align="center">Preço</th>
                <th align="center">Imagem</th>
                <th align="center">Operações</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <?php echo $conteudotabela; ?>

        </tbody>

    <?php   
        }
    ?>

    </div>
```

Agradeço a atenção dos amigos.

Comment: Às vezes menos é mais. Esse código completo só atrapalha a questão, fica difícil entender o que você quer fazer. Exatamente aonde está o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer pegar o resultado da primeira consulta para exibir na segunda, correto?

Vou supor que a consulta a quant_img vai retornar um resultado.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quant_img");
// query, linha, coluna
echo mysql_result($query , 0, "editar");
```

Nesse echo você vai obter a **primeira linha** da consulta acima, e vai mostrar o valor da coluna **editar**

Answer (score 0):

#### Problemas

- Você tem tags `meta charset` no meio do seu código, tags `meta` devem ficar no `head` da pagina, e você só pode especificar uma vez o `charset`, pois que ele quer dizer que o documente segue aquele padrão de unicode.
- `$total_registros` não esta sendo usado logo abaixo você repete `mysql_num_rows($sql_listar);`
- `$conteudotabela` não foi iniciado você esta deixando o PHP definir o valor inicial (ainda bem que ele é de tipagem fraca né?)
- Sua ultima `table` não tem um termino `</table>`.
- Eu não achei, a quem pertence `<?php } ?>` logo apos a tabela sem termino.

#### Sobre quant_img

Você deve ter alguma foreignKey para relacionar `quant_img` com `produto`, assim você pode realizar uma unica *Query* para saber os dados necessarios, caso seja um relacionamento 1:1.
Se for um 1:N é melhor realizar a consulta de `quant_img` dentro do seu laço `while` adicionando `WHERE codigo = {$id};`, algo assim, e então fazer mais um `while` para as N imagens.